# Should I go with laminate if I have bouncy subfloor

Tags: flooring, subfloor, laminate-floor, laminate

I started the installation of a laminate and noticed that some parts of my 2nd floor subfloor is bouncing when I step on it. Even after I install laminate and take a step on it I still feel a little of bouncing.
Is it gonna affect laminate?
(I sanded down seems between plywood sheets and using an underlayment + 12mm laminate)

Answer (score 1):

No.  Laminate floor is not a magic boo-boo fixer for irregular sub-floors.

The exact opposite, in fact.  Laminate floor is very picky, and will fail prematurely if there are subfloor problems.

You'll need to have that subfloor absolutely mint before laying laminate.  If that's too much trouble lay something less finicky, like T&G.